# Shell script multiplication

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Ive viewed many different forums for this and I keep getting the same syntax error "*" or it echos *

This is a shell script in VIM

This ~ should ~ work but it's leaving me with this output. Help is appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Should be used as a multiplication

Comment: [Please do not upload images of input/code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also, the syntax of your `read` commands is all wrong. Don't use `$` on the variable (that's how you *get* the value, not how you *set* it), and there must be a space between the prompt string and the variable name.

Comment: Next time, please pass your script to https://shellcheck.net before asking human help (we are not ChatGPT)

Comment: If you run your script with `set -x` turned on, you will see that your variables `l` and `w` are empty.

Answer (score 1):

In modern shell:

```
#asking for length

read -p "Enter Length (ft): >>> " len
read -p "Enter Width (ft): >>> " wid
area=$((len * wid))

echo "The area of the room is: $area"
```

---

`expr` is a program used in ancient shell code to do math.
This syntax has been obsolete for a few decades.
In Posix shells like bash, use `$(( expression ))`.
In bash, ksh, mksh, pdksh or zsh, you can also use `(( expression ))`

---

The *backquote* is used in the old-style command substitution. The `foo=$(command)` syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside `$()` is less surprising, and `$()` is easier to nest. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

---

To go deeper, check inputs to prevent shell injection:

```
$ echo 'a[$(uname >&2)]'  | bash -c 'read num; echo $((num+1))'
Linux
1
```

```
case $var in
    '')
        printf 'var is empty\n'
    ;;
    *[!0123456789]*)
        printf '%s has a non-digit somewhere in it\n' "$var"
    ;;
esac >&2
```